# podspec dependencies, best practices

Tags: cocoapods

I am building a cocoapod and wanted to add a dependency for Alamofire because my pod will be making some requests.

After trying to integrate my cocoapod (with the Alamofire dependency) into our main app, I got a version conflict because we are also using Alamofire in our app, but a different version.

Seeing this error, it made us wonder.. why havn't we seen a version conflict message like this one before? We have a handful of third-party cocoapods installed. After inspecting a few of our third-party pod spec files, we found that none of them have dependencies defined.

Is this common practice when releasing cocoapods, to have no dependencies?

(..asked by a Node.js developer)

Answer (score 0):

Remember Alamofire now is on version 4.0(there is even a branch for swift 3), so, if you updated your pods, it automatically installed the new version, if this what you want take a look to [the migration guide](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Alamofire%204.0%20Migration%20Guide.md).

Other case, you have to specify the version you wanna wortk with in your pod file

Comment: Was asking more along the lines of what is the best practice